# Optimal implementation of custom intermediary model

Tags: django

```
    class C:
        attribute_c = models.CharField()

    class B:
        class_a = models.ForeignKey(A)
        class_c = models.ForeignKey(C)
        foo = models.SomeField(null=True)
        boo = models.SomeOtherField(null=True)

    class A:
        items = models.ManyToManyField(C, through='B')
        attribute_a = models.CharField()
        attribute_b = models.IntegerField()
        attribute_c = models.DateField()
        attribute_d = models.ForeignKeyField()
        [...]
```

To create a relation between `class A` and `class C`, the method `save_m2m()` can be called in the forms. However since a custom relation is being used (`class B`), you have to create it yourself, by calling `B.objects.create(instance_of_a, instance_of_b)`.

How can I create this relation without having to manually do it in Forms.py? Maybe overriding the `add()` method (`A.items.add()`) to remove a validation Django does that subsequently throws the error below?

> Cannot set values on a ManyToManyField which specifies an intermediary
>   model. Use app.B's Manager instead.

I have classes that are very similar to the ones I wrote above. They have been working fine until now, when some requirements changed. These requirements forced me to introduce a custom intermediary class, adding the attributes `foo` and `boo`. 
I have a ton of tests using [FactoryBoy](https://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/orms.html) and thus creating instances of `class A` without using forms. If I have to manually insert this relation everytime I create an instance of `class A`, it will be a pain.

What is the best way to circumvent this problem?

I basically need to have the relation between A and C created without being bothered to fulfill these attributes on B. I can do that through a signal or something.

PS: I'm using Django 1.11.17.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with *create a relation between `A` and `C` without doing it through forms*? You can create a `B` object, like `B.object.create(class_a=some_a, class_c=some_c)`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I've updated the question. I want to override the `.add()` method, but maybe there is a better idea.

Comment: Why not make a `ModelForm` on the `B` model. In that case the form will contain two items to select the `A` and `C` for the relation, together with the fields to add the `B` model object.

Comment: I should have mentioned that `class A` has a tun of other attributes that also need to be fulfilled. Basically, the main class is `class A`. It will be a problem, from an user experience point of view (and also from the tests part) to have it like that.

Comment: I basically need to have the relation between A and C created without being bothered to fulfill these attributes on B. I can do that through a signal or something.

Comment: I believe that what you want is part of what is being added in [Django 2.2](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/2.2/) so maybe you can backport from there... or just wait and upgrade.

Comment: Hmm. I will use a monkey-patch to get this around until I can migrate to this version then. I guess it'll be better to just wait.